# postgresql passwordcheck windows server

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have a windows server with installed postgresql.
I would like to enable passwordcheck extension but is not present and do not know where to find it.
Can someone help me?
Thanks so much

Comment: Did you read this - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/passwordcheck.html ?

Comment: yes of course but  I did not find any documentation on how to install under windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be installed (look for `passwordcheck.dll` in the `lib` directory), but you need to enable it by adding it to `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgresql.conf` and restarting the database server.

Just follow [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/passwordcheck.html).

Comment: ok Thanks a lot I have passwordcheck.dll in lib directory ..and now? I have to put this file in C:Windows/System32 ? or I should do something else?     Another question :The password check documentation (what are the controls etc..) where can I find it?
Thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: I have added a link to the documentation. Read and follow it, and report back if you encounter problems.

Comment: hi.Im sorry Im a newbie
 I added the following line in postgresql.conf
shared_preload_libraries = 'C: \ Program Files \ PostgreSQL \ 9.4 \ lib \ passwordcheck.dll' #
I restarted the db but it seems nothing happened

Comment: The documentation says to use `$libdir` (literally) and not an absolute path. Looking at the PostgreSQL server log should help.